# Check whether Child Process has terminated in C on Unix without blocking

Tags: c, unix, process, fork, parent

I would like to check whether / when a child process has terminated in C on Unix. It's not supposed to be blocking, rather a short check in a loop.
My code:

```
pid_t pid = fork();
if (pid > 0)
    // Parent Process
    while (1) {
        // Do a short check whether Child has already terminated if yes break the loop.
    // Ik that it's possible to use waitpid(pid, &status, 0) but that blocks the whole loop until the child has terminated 

    }
if (pid == 0)
    printf("child process born");
    exit(0);
```

Thx in advance

Comment: At first grance, the assignment `pid = 0` looks weird.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The third argument to `waitpid` is a set of flags.  If you pass `WNOHANG` to this argument, the function will return immediately if no children have yet exited.

You can then check if `waitpid` returned 0.  If so, no child exited and you wait and try again.

```
while (1) {
    pid_t rval = waitpid(pid, &status, WNOHANG);

    if (rval == -1) {
        perror("waitpid failed");
        exit(1);
    } else if (rval == 0) {
        sleep(1);
    } else {
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: When `waitpid(..., WNOHANG)` returns immediately because no child has exited, it doesn't write a meaningful value to `status`.  Your sample code should check for `rval > 0` before looking at `status` (either -1 or 0 may be returned to indicate no status changes are reportable, see https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/waitpid.html RETURN VALUE section).

Comment: Also, there are cases where `waitpid` reports that a child has something-ed but _neither_ `WIFEXITED(status)` nor `WIFSIGNALED(status)` is true.

Comment: @zwol Should've read the docs more closely... Fixed.

Comment: For reduced latency, you could thread off the waitpid and communicate with the loop via an atomic boolean.  Checking a bool is much quicker than a system call.

Answer (score 1):

Traditional way is:

```
#include <errno.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int exist(pid_t pid) {
   return kill(pid, 0) > 0 || errno != ESRCH;
}
int main(int ac, char **av) {
    while (--ac > 0) {
        pid_t p = strtol(*++av, 0, 0);
        printf("%d %s\n", p, exist(p) ? "exists" : "doesn't exist");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

It doesn't care about parent : child relation (whereas wait derivatives do), and works even if you don't have permission to affect the process.